# CLLocationManager returning Nil value

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the CLLocationManager in order to return a users location in the form of two coordinates.

- I think I have the proper authorization (`authorizedWhenInUse`) but when it comes to getting the actual location it returns `nil`.
- I also have `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` added to my plist

  ```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation    
  class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {  
  // Create an instance of the CLLocationManager
      var locManager = CLLocationManager()

  // View did load function (run things inside of here)
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      locManager.delegate = self
      locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

      // Check authorizationStatus
      let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
      // List out all responses
      switch authorizationStatus {
      case .AuthorizedAlways:
          println("authorized")
      case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
          println("authorized when in use")
      case .Denied:
          println("denied")
      case .NotDetermined:
          println("not determined")
      case .Restricted:
          println("restricted")
      }

      // Get the location
      locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

      if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){
          // Extract the location from CLLocationManager
          let userLocation = locManager.location

          // Check to see if it is nil
          if userLocation != nil {
              println("location is \(userLocation)")
          } else {
              println("location is nil")
          }
      } else {
          println("not authorized")
      }

      }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

The CLLocationManager.h header file in the SDK gives this helpful hint about the "`.location`" property:

```
Discussion:
 *      The last location received. Will be nil until a location has been received.
```

The best thing to do is implement the:

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

delegate method and get your location out of there, which gets called when the device's GPS resolves where the phone is.

Something like:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let userLocation = manager.location

    print("location = \(userLocation.latitude) \(userLocation.longitude)")

  }
```

Comment: I realize that it will be Nil if the location has not been determined, but why does `locManager.startUpdatingLocation()` fail to provide the location?

Comment: it does take up to a few seconds for a location to be resolved.  Also, you should implement the ["`locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`" delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:) to let you know when something failed (e.g. the user didn't give permission for the location manager to be used?)